# Get cell label text when selected

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying the get the Text in Label ID `nameLabel` when i click on the cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
    // get text in label nameLabel

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With MVC you get this information from the model, not from the view.

Since you have the indexPath of the cell, you can use that to get the object that the cell is displaying from the data source.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a data Model to keep all the data of your cells. When you select a cell, this function will be called

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // indexPath is the cell you selected
    // you can use indexPath.row to get the data from the data Model
}
```

Your Data Model may be a dic or an Array / set and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a custom cell (In the code snippet I assumed that its class name is `MyCustomCell`), containing a label (In the code snippet I assumed that the label's name is `nameLabel`), it should something like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
    // get text in label nameLabel
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

    // here is the text of the label
    let string = selectedCell.nameLabel.text
}
```